# Doctrine Object Select not hydrating as object

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a form with a fieldset which contains a Doctrine ObjectSelect element.

```
$this->add(array(
'name' => 'vatRate',
'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
'options' => array(
    'label' => _('VAT Rate:'),
    'object_manager' => $this->getEntityManager(),
    'target_class' => 'Application\Entity\VatRates',
    'property' => 'title',
    'is_method' => true,
    'find_method' => array(
        'name' => 'getVatRatesOrderRate',
    ),
    'label_generator' => function($targetEntity) {
        return $targetEntity->getTitle() . ' (' . $targetEntity->getVatRate() . '%)';
    },
    'disable_inarray_validator' => TRUE,
),
```

));

In my invoiceItems entity I have

```
/**
 * @var \Application\Entity\VatRates
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\VatRates")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="vat_rate_id", referencedColumnName="vat_rate_id")
 * })
 */
private $vatRate;

/**
 *
 * @param VatRates|NULL $vatRate
 * @return \Application\Entity\InvoiceItems
 */
public function setVatRate(VatRates $vatRate = NULL)
{
    $this->vatRate = $vatRate;
    return $this;
}
```

The problem I am having is that when I validate the form Doctrine's DoctrineObject hydrator is not converting the vatRate to an entity before passing it to the setter. I get the following error.

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Application\Entity\InvoiceItems::setVatRate() must be an instance of Application\Entity\VatRates, integer given, called in C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\My Webs\freedomsnew\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-module\src\DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject.php on line 282 and defined in C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\My Webs\freedomsnew\module\Application\src\Application\Entity\InvoiceItems.php on line 339
```

As can be seen by the error message the integer vatRateId is being sent to the invoiceItems entity setVatRate method.

I have other forms/fieldsets setup in a similar way and all work with no problems.  Does anyone know what I have done wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Doctrine had cached the entity. Clearing the cache solved the problem.

```
php ./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:clear-cache:query
php ./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:clear-cache:metadata
php ./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:clear-cache:result
```

I setup a batch file to do this from now on.